# How do I use the subscriber option?

Tags: php, real-time, subscriber, websub

I started now with Pubsubhubbub (and all about realtime things), but I amhaving trouble with the Subscriber option.

I'm trying to develop a webapp in PHP to:

1. Subscribe a RSS (previously Published) to the Hub (http://pubsubhubbub.appspot.com/);
2. Read notifications (updates) from the Hub for the subscription;
   without succeed!!! :(

I verify that exist a library in [php to the Subscriber](http://pubsubhubbub.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/subscriber_clients/php/) (in Git), but
using this lib can't make the Subscribe work's (get a 409 error!).

How can I do this?

Comment: A 409 error is a *conflict* and - in pubsubhubbub - occurs when subscription verification fails

Comment: OK , I opened the bounty ,but I can't edit @ddluis 's question ,so I am going to ask here.

And how exactly to implement this - http://github.com/lxbarth/PuSHSubscriber/ class?I don't get this part:Integration with host applications

Answer (score 3):

This is an old question and the PHP library ddluis linked to has many flaws.

The recommended PHP subscriber in the Google Code wiki is PuSHSubscriber:

http://github.com/lxbarth/PuSHSubscriber/

**UPDATE:**

I forked PuSHSubscriber: http://github.com/bobdia/PuSHSubscriber

I've made a few incompatible changes with the original. A simple implementation can be found in the [/example](http://github.com/bobdia/PuSHSubscriber/tree/master/example/) directory. This is not meant for real use, just for demonstration purposes. I hope you find it useful.

Comment: And why not
http://pubsubhubbub.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/subscriber_clients/php/subscriber.php ?
It simpler!

Comment: And how exactly to implement the above class?I don't get this part:Integration with host applications

Comment: The php class that the OP linked to seems simpler because it doesn't really do much. PuSHSubscriber is quite simple and does everything you need except storing the notifications it receives. I decided to make an example implementation with it, so check back in a day or two and I'll post a link to something everyone can easily understand.

Comment: So ,what exactly SubscriptionInterface and EnvironmentInterface have to implement?

Comment: What happened @bobdiaes ? What's your progress?

Comment: I found the interfaces - they are at the end of the script!

Comment: I've updated my answer with links to the example implementation. Enjoy!

Comment: Hmm , it doesn't log anything in  notifications.log. I use PubSubHubbub plugin for wordpress and I use and my own blog to try this ,but it don't work.
In system.log:Positive response to "subscribe" request

Answer (score 3):

The first thing I'd try is forget about libraries and try to understand what's happening in the context of a subscriber exactly. It should be really really straightforward to build a script that handles all this together.

A subscriber application must do 2 things :

- Acknowledge the susbcription : the hub will verify the intent of the susbcriber. It's a GET request
- Deal with incoming pings. It's a POST request.

So let's start :

1. Put a script somewhere on the web (it must be accessible from behind a firewall) which must be bale to handle to GET requests from the hub. Make sure it *only* echoes the `hub.challenge` param that it gets in the response's body and returns 200.
2. Send the following from your command line : `curl -X POST http://pubsubhubbub.appspot.com/ -d'hub.mode=subscribe' -d'hub.verify=sync' -d'hub.topic=http://the.feed.url' -d'hub.callback=http://the.script.url' -D-`
3. You should see an incoming verification request on the script. Ideally (if you followed step 1, it should echo the hub.challenge and return a 200.

If this was all fine the curl request that you send should tell you that the hub returned a 204. If you get anything else, check the body of the response, it will indicate you what went wrong.

Later...

1. Your script will get a POST request. This is a notification of new content!
2. Parse the raw body (XML) of this POST request, it contains the feed, only with the new entries.
3. Do whatever needs to be done with the parsed content (save into a database... etc).

I hope this helps. You can [also use this tool](https://pubsubhubbub.appspot.com/subscribe) to debug your subscription of you need help.

Comment: I don't get part 1. "which must be bale to handle to GET requests from the hub" Do I have anything that I need to do with PHP here? And how to "Parse the raw body (XML) of this POST request, it contains the feed, only with the new entries. " - with simpleXML?

Comment: Well, the hub will perform HTTP GET request to your script, so this script must be "accessible" from the web.

Comment: And yes, you can use simpleXML to parse the body of the POST request.

Answer (score 1):

Some code that may be helpful, with good docs:

- [Zend Framework: Documentation: Zend_Feed_Pubsubhubbub - Zend Framework Manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.feed.pubsubhubbub.introduction.html)

Example feed agregator:

- [padraic's ZFPlanet at master - GitHub](http://github.com/padraic/ZFPlanet)