# Can't get Superfeedr callback response in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, superfeedr

I already added this URL to my subscribers list: http://push-pub.appspot.com/

BTW, I also setting well the callback URL, like: http://online-domain.com/data/forward

My controller code:

```
public function forward() {
    $this->autoRender = false
    CakeLog::write('debug', 'Callback work!!');
    CakeLog::write('debug', json_encode($this->request->data));
}
```

But, in my `debug.log`:

```
2013-12-23 06:06:47 Debug: Callback work!!
2013-12-23 06:06:47 Debug:
2013-12-23 06:07:38 Debug: Callback work!!
2013-12-23 06:07:38 Debug:
2013-12-23 06:12:59 Debug: Callback work!!
2013-12-23 06:12:59 Debug:
```

I no idea why `$this->request->data` not working, it should get the callback data from superfeedr. I want get callback from superfeedr. Any guys know what was I wrong? Thanks you in advance.

Comment: Question is not clear...

Comment: I want get callback data from superfeedr.

Comment: Did you check whether superfeedr returns any data?

Comment: Thanks guys for help. I already fixed this. https://github.com/adrinavarro/Superfeedr.php/blob/master/Superfeedr.php#L239

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not familiar with CakePHP, however, I know that most frameworks will assume that the body of a POST request is the content from a form and hence will fail to show the content from a Superfeedr notification. You want to access the "raw" version of the BODY. [This answer may](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3952384/how-to-use-superfeedr-with-php) be able to help (provided you can access the right variables directly).

Answer (score 0):

You have to echo de hub_challege in get request. Somesthing like this.

```
  if(isset($_Get["hub_challenge"])){
   echo $_Get["hub_challenge"];
   return;
}
```